# Cross site error when consumes = "application/json" present

Tags: angular, spring

i am using angular 2 and spring 4. In my controller i set response header like below

```
this.res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
this.res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
```

And use this line below to handle the request.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/api/movieCategory/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody   
    public String createMovieCategory(ModelMap model,HttpServletResponse res, @RequestParam Map<String,String> allRequestParams,
            HttpServletRequest req ) {
```

works perfectly fine. No cross site errors , but when i add consumes = "application/json" parameter to @RequestMapping i get the below error. I don`t understand what is happening. Any ideas ?

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8080/api/movieCategory/create. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 415.

Answer (score 1):

Set the client side header `content-type: application/json`

In your angular service import Headers and RequestOptions from `@angular/http`

```
import {Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers} from '@angular/http';
```

then somewhere before your post:

```
const headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
const options = new RequestOptions( {headers: headers});
```

and then make the post, passing in your options object:

```
...
this.http.post("/api/movieCategory/create", someData, options)
...
```

When you are adding the `consumes = "application/json"` option, you explicitly say that the server expects application/json datatype. If the cors request is made without specifying the datatype then you get your 415 error. Adding the header at the client side should allow the client to tell the server that the data it has sent in the request IS of `application/json` and should be accepted.

Comment: It says can not find name RequestOptions ?

Comment: Updated my answer - if it can't find RequestOptions, there may be an issue with your import statement

Comment: Thanks for the answer, now i get Refused to set unsafe header "Access-Control-Request-Method" from chrome

Comment: Not seen that before, are you able to add the code for the request in angular to the question to see it?

Comment: @rematnarab  You don’t show it in the code snippet in the question but the only reason you’d be getting *“Refused to set unsafe header "Access-Control-Request-Method"”* is if you have frontend JavaScript code that’s trying to manually add that header to your request. You don’t want to do that, because Access-Control-Request-Method is a header that’s only set by the browser automatically, only for CORS preflight OPTIONS request that the browser itself sends. So you need to remove whatever code you added to your frontend JavaScript that’s trying to add that.